# Error updating all NuGet packages across Solution using IgnoreDependencies

Tags: visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package

I am trying to update my NuGet packages across the solution to the latest version, but using 'IgnoreDependencies' for each package.
I'd like to do this with one click or one command if possible.

Individually updating each package across the solution with `IgnoreDependencies` works fine, but is very tedious.
I tried to use Visual Studio 2015 (Update-3)'s 'Select all packages' -> 'Update' button to do this in one go, however I get an error that just says 'packages', and nothing else. (Possibly a bug in the VS2015 NuGet UI?)

I've attempted this in the UI (where I get this error), and I also tried in the Package Manager Console, using `update-package -IgnoreDependencies`, but this still pulls in the dependencies regardless of the flag.

Am I stuck with updating each package individually (still across multiple projects at least, which is something I suppose), or is there something I'm missing so that I can do this across all projects, for all packages, ignoring dependencies?

Comment: I could update packages in the NuGet UI, what is your Nuget package version? You could install the update for NuGET/VS update 3 from the Extensions and Updates window. In Package Manager console, if I run the same command line, it would update the dependencies packages to the lowest version(you could also get the option in the NuGet UI under "Install and Update Options").

Comment: Can all the packages be updated individually? The "packages" error message is an exception when there is something wrong with package identity. I'm wondering that if there is one package in your project has issue which cause the error when you update all packages together.